# Drupal access to und array

Tags: arrays, drupal-7, undefined

I am attempting to read an array of key index **UND** using the following code:

```
dsm( $node->$settings['field'][$node->language] );
```

The settings array contains the following:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 70
    [type] => event
    [field] => field_event_form_s_
)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$f in webform_questionnaire_validation_init() (line 27 of /var/www/mysite/sites/all/modules/anthonynolan/webform_questionnaire_validation/webform_questionnaire_validation.module).
```

***UPDATE***

Code from line 27 as requested:

```
dsm( $node->$settings['field'][$node->language] );
```

Comment: can you paste whats the code around line 27 in webform_questionnaire_validation.module) ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added the code from line 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$node->{$settings['field']}[$node->language]`.

I tried with the following test code, and it works.

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->language = 'und';
$node->field_event_form_s_ = array(
  'und' => array( 0 => 'Bingo!'),
);

$settings = array(
  'field' => 'field_event_form_s_'
);

dsm($node->{$settings['field']}[$node->language]);
```

When I replace the last line with `dsm($node->$settings['field'][$node->language]);` I get the following error, as you do:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$f in eval() (line 11 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/dr72/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module(1285) : eval()'d code).